# Update de cada linha de uma tabela através de um dropdown construido por uma matriz associativa

Tags: javascript, html

Pretendo criar uma tabela onde um dos campos é do tipo drop down, constituído pelos valores chave de uma matriz associativa e de acordo com a chave que se escolhe, uma segunda coluna é atualizada automaticamente com o valor correspondente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A matriz associativa tem a seguinte forma:

```
$JusRes=array(
"Jus 1"=>"Resp 1",
"Jus 2"=>"Resp 2",
"Jus 3"=>"Resp 3"
);
```

Função javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function mudaRes(indice){   
    var just=document.getElementById('Just');   
    var selectedOption = just.options[just.selectedIndex];  
    var respValue = selectedOption.getAttribute('Resp');
    var resp=document.getElementById('DadosTab');   
    var Re=document.getElementById('Res');  
    Re.value = respValue;
    resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].innerHTML = respValue; 
}

</script>
```

Esta configuração só funciona quando eu clicko a primeira vez na primeira linha, o dado correscpondente é colocado na coluna Resp e consigo guardar esse dado, o problema é quando clicko na segunda linha, a partir daqui, não funciona mais a atualização da coluna "Resp" nem consigo obter os dados escolhidos.

Pretendo guardar os dados, para no fim de clicar em "Send" inserir na BD.

Constituição da tabela:

```
<table id='DadosTab'>
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Sobrenome</th>
    <th>Idade</th>    
    <th>Just</th>   
    <th>Resp</th>   
  </tr>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; 
$indtd=0;
$indtr=0;
foreach ($Dados as $chave=>$valor){
    echo "<tr id='".$indtr."'>";
    //nome
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='nome[]' value='".$Dados[$indtr][0]."' />".$Dados[$indtr][0]."</td>";
    $indtd++;
    //sobrenome
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='hidden' name='sobrenome[]' value='".$Dados[$indtr][1]."' />".$Dados[$indtr][1]."</td>";
    $indtd++;
    //idade 
    echo "<td align='center'><input type='text' name='idade[]' value='".$Dados[$indtr][2]."' /></td>";
    $indtd++;
    //echo "<td align='center'>".$Dados[$ind][2]."</td>";   
    echo "<td><select id='Just' name='Just[]' style='width: 220px' onchange=mudaRes($indtr)>";
    $indtd++;
        echo "<OPTION>Tipo de Justificacao</OPTION>";
        foreach ($JusRes as $Jus=>$Resp){
            echo "<OPTION id='".$indtr."' Resp='".$Resp."' value='".$Jus."'>".$Jus."</OPTION>";
        }   
    echo "</select></td>";
    echo "<td align='center'><input id='Res' type='hidden' name='Res[]' /></td>";
    $indtd++;   
    echo "</tr>";    
    $indtr++;
}
echo "<tr><th align='left' colspan='5'><input type='submit' value='Send' name='Send'></th></tr>";
echo "</form>";
```

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está repetindo dois `id`s dentro do laço `foreach`. Isso dá errado porque no JS você está selecionando esses `id`'s como se fossem únicos. O mesmo `id` nunca pode ser repetido, ele deve ser único na página.

Se você tem mais de um elemento com o mesmo `id` e tenta fazer isso:

```
var Re=document.getElementById('Res');
```

Irá pegar apenas o primeiro elemento com o id "Res".

O que você deve fazer é criar `id`'s diferentes em sequência dentro do laço, pode utilizar a variável `$indtr` que você está incrementando `++` a cada loop. Basta colocá-lo dentro dos dois `id`'s repetitivos:

Aqui:

```
                            ↓
echo "<td><select id='Just$indtr' name='Just[]' style='width: 220px' onchange='mudaRes(this, $indtr)'>";
```

E aqui:

```
                                         ↓
echo "<td align='center'><input id='Res$indtr' type='hidden' name='Res[]' /></td>";
```

Em seguida você deve enviar pelo `onchange`, além do código que já está lá da variável `$indtr`, o próprio `select` representado pelo `this`, e envolver o valor do `onchange` por aspas simples:

```
onchange='mudaRes(this, $indtr)'
```

Adicione na `td` antes do `input hidden` um `span` vazio para receber o texto. Isso facilitará o processo e você não precisará usar `innerHTML` na função:

```
                           ↓      ↓
echo "<td align='center'><span></span><input id='Res$indtr' type='hidden' name='Res[]' /></td>";
```

E na função, adicionar mais um parâmetro para receber o `this` (no caso, pode usar `just` que já contém na função):

```
function mudaRes(just, indice){...
```

Aí você pode remover a linha `var just=document.getElementById('Just');` porque o `just` já vem como parâmetro.

E na linha var `Re=document.getElementById('Res'+indice);` você concatena a variável `indice` para pegar o respectivo `id`.

Coloque na função também o código para colocar o texto no `span`:

```
var resp_txt = resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].querySelector("span");
resp_txt.innerHTML = respValue;
```

E remova a linha `resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].innerHTML = respValue;` que já não é necessária.

A função toda ficará assim:

```
function mudaRes(just, indice){   
    var selectedOption = just.options[just.selectedIndex];  
    var respValue = selectedOption.getAttribute('Resp');
    var resp=document.getElementById('DadosTab');   
    var Re=document.getElementById('Res'+indice);  
    Re.value = respValue;
    var resp_txt = resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].querySelector("span");
    resp_txt.innerHTML = respValue;
}
```

Com todas essas alterações irá funcionar perfeitamente.

Exemplo funcional sem PHP, para ilustrar o funcionamento (retirei o `hidden` do input para poder visualizar o valor):

```js
function mudaRes(just, indice){   
    var selectedOption = just.options[just.selectedIndex];  
    var respValue = selectedOption.getAttribute('Resp');
    var resp=document.getElementById('DadosTab');   
    var Re=document.getElementById('Res'+indice);  
    Re.value = respValue;
    var resp_txt = resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].querySelector("span");
    resp_txt.innerHTML = respValue;
//    resp.rows[indice+1].cells[4].innerHTML = respValue;
}
```

```html
<table id="DadosTab">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Sobrenome</th>
    <th>Idade</th>    
    <th>Just</th>   
    <th>Resp</th>   
  </tr><form action="" method="POST"></form><tr id="0"><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value=""></td><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="sobrenome[]" value=""></td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="idade[]" value=""></td><td><select id="Just0" name="Just[]" style="width: 220px" onchange="mudaRes(this, 0)"><option>Tipo de Justificacao</option><option id="0" resp="Resp 1" value="Jus 1">Jus 1</option><option id="0" resp="Resp 2" value="Jus 2">Jus 2</option><option id="0" resp="Resp 3" value="Jus 3">Jus 3</option></select></td><td align="center"><span></span><input id="Res0" name="Res[]"></td></tr><tr id="1"><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value=""></td><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="sobrenome[]" value=""></td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="idade[]" value=""></td><td><select id="Just1" name="Just[]" style="width: 220px" onchange="mudaRes(this, 1)"><option>Tipo de Justificacao</option><option id="1" resp="Resp 1" value="Jus 1">Jus 1</option><option id="1" resp="Resp 2" value="Jus 2">Jus 2</option><option id="1" resp="Resp 3" value="Jus 3">Jus 3</option></select></td><td align="center"><span></span><input id="Res1" name="Res[]"></td></tr><tr id="2"><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="nome[]" value="d"></td><td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="sobrenome[]" value=""></td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="idade[]" value=""></td><td><select id="Just2" name="Just[]" style="width: 220px" onchange="mudaRes(this, 2)"><option>Tipo de Justificacao</option><option id="2" resp="Resp 1" value="Jus 1">Jus 1</option><option id="2" resp="Resp 2" value="Jus 2">Jus 2</option><option id="2" resp="Resp 3" value="Jus 3">Jus 3</option></select></td><td align="center"><span></span><input id="Res2" name="Res[]"></td></tr><tr><th align="left" colspan="5"><input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send"></th></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: É frustrante andar de volta do problema e saber que estive quase a resolve-lo. @Sam funciona cinco estrelas.